# Match input with array pairs

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a script which automatically shows a price depending on the entered value.

My price discounts could be:

```
1 item or more = "£5";
5 items or more = "£30";
10 items or more = "£55";
```

So when the user types "7" in an input box, the price is displayed as `£30*7`.

The only way I know how to do this is by making an if else statement for each case, but I am guessing there's an easier way?

This is my pseudo code:

```
<script>

function calc() {
var amountVar = document.getElementById('amount').value;

var discount = new Array();
discount[1] = "£5";
discount[5] = "£30";
discount[10] = "£55";

match = discount where amountVar matches key or more;

document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = match;
}

</script>

<input onkeyup="calc();" id="amount">
<br>
Price: <p id="price"></p>
```

Comment: Are those discounts per item or for the whole purchase? Shouldn't the price be (price - discount)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than an `if/else`, you can put them all in an array and just go through the array in a `for` loop until you find the matching discount.  This has several advantages, the main one being that it's trivial to edit the discounts array without writing new code.

```
// array must be sorted by qty
var discounts = [{qty:1, discount:5}, {qty:5, discount:30}, {qty:10, discount:55}];

function calcPrice (qty) {
    qty = +qty;

    if (qty > 0)
    {
      // look through the array from the end and find first matching discount
      for (var i = discounts.length; i--;) {
          if (qty >= discounts[i].qty) {
              return discounts[i].discount;
          }
      }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you jfriend, but I tried it and it just ouputs 55 no matter what I enter. I used <input onkeyup="calcPrice(this.value);" id="amount">

Comment: It should probably be in the reverse order (largest to smallest), and the comparator should be `>=`

Comment: @JohnSmith - did you convert `this.value` to a number?

Comment: @Shmiddty - why reverse order?

Comment: @JohnSmith `this.value` is a value of type `String`. Try `+this.value`, `parseFloat(this.value)`, or `parseInt(this.value, 10)`, or do the type conversion to `Number` in `calcPrice()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 With your solution as-is, it's going to say the discount is 30 for qty between 2 and 5.

Comment: @jfriend00 For `qty === 4`, the discount should be 5, not 30.  Reverse order is necessary so that the discounts for greater quantities are tried first.

Comment: @PointedEars - I interpreted the discount algorithm differently than you did, but after re-reading the question, your interpretation is probably what the OP meant so I'll accept your edits - Thx.